# EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT) vuforia native iOS

Tags: ios, sigabrt, vuforia

My application was rejected from the app store due to crash. But I can not reproduce this. I am using:

- latest Vuforia iOS SDK 5.0.6
- Xcode 7.1.1.
- Universal type of the app.
- Deployment target: 8.0

Here is the symbolicated crash log from the reviewer:

```
Incident Identifier: 34C28097-0C86-4F0E-B86E-97D9AEF01B47
CrashReporter Key:   d1e7d132ee8d12443732148f9bad405a6f95d681
Hardware Model:      xxx
Process:             MyApp [1041]
Path:                /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/C1E47878-E660-490F-8058-70E300F039ED/MyApp.app/MyApp
Identifier:          com.zizlabs.MyApp
Version:             1 (1.0)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2015-12-07 11:54:50.50 -0800
Launch Time:         2015-12-07 11:54:00.00 -0800
OS Version:          iOS 9.1 (13B143)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x18366cf48 __exceptionPreprocess + 124
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x1984b3f80 objc_exception_throw + 56
2   CoreFoundation                  0x18366ce90 +[NSException raise:format:] + 120
3   UIKit                           0x188c7856c -[UIViewController __supportedInterfaceOrientations] + 912
4   UIKit                           0x188c77efc -[UIViewController _preferredInterfaceOrientationGivenStatusBarAndDeviceAndOrientation:] + 96
5   UIKit                           0x188edc9f8 -[UIApplicationRotationFollowingController _preferredInterfaceOrientationGivenCurrentOrientation:] + 172
6   UIKit                           0x188c01704 -[UIWindow _updateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:force:] + 328
7   UIKit                           0x189084854 -[UIScreen _notifyOrientationWillChangeAndPropagateToAllWindows:] + 344
8   UIKit                           0x189082e34 -[UIScreen _computeMetrics:] + 1524
9   UIKit                           0x1890838cc -[UIScreen _setInterfaceOrientation:computeMetrics:animated:] + 108
10  UIKit                           0x188eaa7d8 -[UIApplication setStatusBarOrientation:animationParameters:notifySpringBoardAndFence:updateBlock:] + 680
11  UIKit                           0x188ef6740 __78-[UIWindow _rotateWindowToOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:skipCallbacks:]_block_invoke1183 + 292
12  UIKit                           0x18924e748 __58-[_UIWindowRotationAnimationController animateTransition:]_block_invoke_2 + 168
13  UIKit                           0x188f124e8 +[UIView(Internal) _performBlockDelayingTriggeringResponderEvents:] + 220
14  UIKit                           0x18924e558 __58-[_UIWindowRotationAnimationController animateTransition:]_block_invoke + 136
15  UIKit                           0x18924e43c -[_UIWindowRotationAnimationController animateTransition:] + 520
16  UIKit                           0x188ef50ec -[UIWindow _rotateToBounds:withAnimator:transitionContext:] + 556
17  UIKit                           0x188ef635c -[UIWindow _rotateWindowToOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:skipCallbacks:] + 1248
18  UIKit                           0x188c83598 -[UIWindow _setRotatableClient:toOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:force:isRotating:] + 1360
19  UIKit                           0x188c82ecc -[UIWindow _setRotatableViewOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:force:] + 172
20  UIKit                           0x1894c01f8 -[_UIFullscreenPresentationController _placeCounterRotationViewWithView:inWindow:fromOrientation:toOrientation:force:] + 352
21  UIKit                           0x1894c0000 -[_UIFullscreenPresentationController _adjustOrientationIfNecessaryInWindow:forViewController:preservingViewController:] + 608
22  UIKit                           0x188f552e4 -[UIPresentationController _presentWithAnimationController:interactionController:target:didEndSelector:] + 1076
23  UIKit                           0x188f78314 -[UIViewController _presentViewController:modalSourceViewController:presentationController:animationController:interactionController:completion:] + 1392
24  UIKit                           0x188f79d94 -[UIViewController _presentViewController:withAnimationController:completion:] + 4644
25  UIKit                           0x188f7c800 -[UIViewController _performCoordinatedPresentOrDismiss:animated:] + 472
26  UIKit                           0x188cf9ea0 -[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:] + 184
27  libdispatch.dylib               0x198cd16e8 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
28  libdispatch.dylib               0x198cd16a8 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
29  libdispatch.dylib               0x198cd6db0 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1844
30  CoreFoundation                  0x1836241f8 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
31  CoreFoundation                  0x183622060 __CFRunLoopRun + 1628
32  CoreFoundation                  0x183550ca0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
33  GraphicsServices                0x18e5e4088 GSEventRunModal + 180
34  UIKit                           0x188c68ffc UIApplicationMain + 204
35  MyApp                           0x1000ce7b0 main (main.m:14)
36  libdyld.dylib                   0x198d028b8 start + 4


Global Trace Buffer (reverse chronological seconds):
0.195619     CFNetwork                  0x0000000182d6da18 TCP Conn 0x136e9bee0 SSL Handshake DONE
0.221597     CFNetwork                  0x0000000182d6d928 TCP Conn 0x136e9bee0 starting SSL negotiation
0.221931     CFNetwork                  0x0000000182e0fa30 TCP Conn 0x136e9bee0 complete. fd: 19, err: 0
0.222710     CFNetwork                  0x0000000182e10f5c TCP Conn 0x136e9bee0 event 1. err: 0
0.304452     CFNetwork                  0x0000000182e11034 TCP Conn 0x136e9bee0 started
29.919706    CFNetwork                  0x0000000182d6da18 TCP Conn 0x138bceff0 SSL Handshake DONE
29.988760    CFNetwork                  0x0000000182d6d928 TCP Conn 0x138bceff0 starting SSL negotiation
29.989114    CFNetwork                  0x0000000182e0fa30 TCP Conn 0x138bceff0 complete. fd: 108, err: 0
29.989605    CFNetwork                  0x0000000182e10f5c TCP Conn 0x138bceff0 event 1. err: 0



Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000198e1f140 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000198ee8ef8 pthread_kill + 112
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000198d92b78 abort + 140
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000197b293f4 __cxa_bad_cast + 0
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000197b45e98 default_unexpected_handler() + 0
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001984b4248 _objc_terminate() + 124
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000197b42f44 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 16
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000197b4285c __cxxabiv1::exception_cleanup_func(_Unwind_Reason_Code, _Unwind_Exception*) + 0
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001984b4094 _objc_exception_destructor(void*) + 0
9   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018366ce90 -[NSException initWithCoder:] + 0
10  UIKit                           0x0000000188c7856c -[UIViewController __supportedInterfaceOrientations] + 912
11  UIKit                           0x0000000188c77efc -[UIViewController _preferredInterfaceOrientationGivenStatusBarAndDeviceAndOrientation:] + 96
12  UIKit                           0x0000000188edc9f8 -[UIApplicationRotationFollowingController _preferredInterfaceOrientationGivenCurrentOrientation:] + 172
13  UIKit                           0x0000000188c01704 -[UIWindow _updateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:force:] + 328
14  UIKit                           0x0000000189084854 -[UIScreen _notifyOrientationWillChangeAndPropagateToAllWindows:] + 344
15  UIKit                           0x0000000189082e34 -[UIScreen _computeMetrics:] + 1524
16  UIKit                           0x00000001890838cc -[UIScreen _setInterfaceOrientation:computeMetrics:animated:] + 108
17  UIKit                           0x0000000188eaa7d8 -[UIApplication setStatusBarOrientation:animationParameters:notifySpringBoardAndFence:updateBlock:] + 680
18  UIKit                           0x0000000188ef6740 __78-[UIWindow _rotateWindowToOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:skipCallbacks:]_block_invoke1183 + 292
19  UIKit                           0x000000018924e748 __58-[_UIWindowRotationAnimationController animateTransition:]_block_invoke_2 + 168
20  UIKit                           0x0000000188f124e8 +[UIView(Internal) _performBlockDelayingTriggeringResponderEvents:] + 220
21  UIKit                           0x000000018924e558 __58-[_UIWindowRotationAnimationController animateTransition:]_block_invoke + 136
22  UIKit                           0x000000018924e43c -[_UIWindowRotationAnimationController animateTransition:] + 520
23  UIKit                           0x0000000188ef50ec -[UIWindow _rotateToBounds:withAnimator:transitionContext:] + 556
24  UIKit                           0x0000000188ef635c -[UIWindow _rotateWindowToOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:skipCallbacks:] + 1248
25  UIKit                           0x0000000188c83598 -[UIWindow _setRotatableClient:toOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:force:isRotating:] + 1360
26  UIKit                           0x0000000188c82ecc -[UIWindow _setRotatableViewOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:force:] + 172
27  UIKit                           0x00000001894c01f8 -[_UIFullscreenPresentationController _placeCounterRotationViewWithView:inWindow:fromOrientation:toOrientation:force:] + 352
28  UIKit                           0x00000001894c0000 -[_UIFullscreenPresentationController _adjustOrientationIfNecessaryInWindow:forViewController:preservingViewController:] + 608
29  UIKit                           0x0000000188f552e4 -[UIPresentationController _presentWithAnimationController:interactionController:target:didEndSelector:] + 1076
30  UIKit                           0x0000000188f78314 -[UIViewController _presentViewController:modalSourceViewController:presentationController:animationController:interactionController:completion:] + 1392
31  UIKit                           0x0000000188f79d94 -[UIViewController _presentViewController:withAnimationController:completion:] + 4644
32  UIKit                           0x0000000188f7c800 -[UIViewController _performCoordinatedPresentOrDismiss:animated:] + 472
33  UIKit                           0x0000000188cf9ea0 -[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:] + 184
34  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000198cd16e8 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
35  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000198cd16a8 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
36  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000198cd6db0 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1844
37  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001836241f8 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
38  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183622060 __CFRunLoopRun + 1628
39  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183550ca0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
40  GraphicsServices                0x000000018e5e4088 GSEventRunModal + 180
41  UIKit                           0x0000000188c68ffc UIApplicationMain + 204
42  MyApp                           0x00000001000ce7b0 main (main.m:14)
43  libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000198d028b8 start + 4

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000198e204fc kevent_qos + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000198ce4a04 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 232
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000198cd3874 _dispatch_source_invoke + 0

Thread 2 name:  GAIThread
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000198e04a40 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000198e048bc mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183624108 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183621e0c __CFRunLoopRun + 1032
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183550ca0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
5   Foundation                      0x00000001844c92bc -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 308
6   Foundation                      0x000000018451e8f4 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 88
7   MyApp                           0x00000001001a8ed4 +[GAI threadMain:] + 64
8   Foundation                      0x00000001845afc80 __NSThread__start__ + 1000
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000198ee7b28 _pthread_body + 156
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000198ee7a8c _pthread_body + 0
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000198ee5028 thread_start + 4

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000198e1fb6c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000198ee5530 _pthread_wqthread + 1284
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000198ee5020 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000198e1fb6c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000198ee5530 _pthread_wqthread + 1284
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000198ee5020 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000198e1fb6c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000198ee5530 _pthread_wqthread + 1284
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000198ee5020 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 6 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000198e04a40 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000198e048bc mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183624108 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183621e0c __CFRunLoopRun + 1032
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183550ca0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
5   CFNetwork                       0x0000000182de9b84 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 412
6   Foundation                      0x00000001845afc80 __NSThread__start__ + 1000
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000198ee7b28 _pthread_body + 156
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000198ee7a8c _pthread_body + 0
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000198ee5028 thread_start + 4

Thread 7 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000198e1f368 __select + 8
1   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018362a670 __CFSocketManager + 648
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000198ee7b28 _pthread_body + 156
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000198ee7a8c _pthread_body + 0
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000198ee5028 thread_start + 4

Thread 8 name:  com.apple.CoreMotion.MotionThread
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000198e04a40 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000198e048bc mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183624108 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183621e0c __CFRunLoopRun + 1032
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183550ca0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
5   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018359e44c CFRunLoopRun + 112
6   CoreMotion                      0x0000000183fd62e4 0x183f84000 + 336612
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000198ee7b28 _pthread_body + 156
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000198ee7a8c _pthread_body + 0
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000198ee5028 thread_start + 4

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000198e1ef48 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000198ee6ce8 _pthread_cond_wait + 648
2   MyApp                           0x0000000100406834 0x100094000 + 3614772
3   MyApp                           0x00000001002df868 0x100094000 + 2406504
4   MyApp                           0x00000001003add94 0x100094000 + 3251604
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000198ee7b28 _pthread_body + 156
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000198ee7a8c _pthread_body + 0
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000198ee5028 thread_start + 4

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000198e04a40 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000198e048bc mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183624108 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183621e0c __CFRunLoopRun + 1032
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183550ca0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
5   Foundation                      0x00000001844c92bc -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 308
6   MyApp                           0x00000001003eac64 0x100094000 + 3501156
7   Foundation                      0x00000001845afc80 __NSThread__start__ + 1000
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000198ee7b28 _pthread_body + 156
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000198ee7a8c _pthread_body + 0
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000198ee5028 thread_start + 4

Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000198e1ef48 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000198ee6ce8 _pthread_cond_wait + 648
2   MyApp                           0x0000000100406904 0x100094000 + 3614980
3   MyApp                           0x00000001003a682c 0x100094000 + 3221548
4   MyApp                           0x00000001005c7c5c 0x100094000 + 5454940
5   MyApp                           0x00000001003add94 0x100094000 + 3251604
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000198ee7b28 _pthread_body + 156
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000198ee7a8c _pthread_body + 0
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000198ee5028 thread_start + 4

Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000198e1ef48 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000198ee6ce8 _pthread_cond_wait + 648
2   MyApp                           0x0000000100406904 0x100094000 + 3614980
3   MyApp                           0x00000001003a682c 0x100094000 + 3221548
4   MyApp                           0x00000001005c7c5c 0x100094000 + 5454940
5   MyApp                           0x00000001003add94 0x100094000 + 3251604
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000198ee7b28 _pthread_body + 156
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000198ee7a8c _pthread_body + 0
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000198ee5028 thread_start + 4

Thread 13:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000198e1ef48 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000198ee6ce8 _pthread_cond_wait + 648
2   MyApp                           0x0000000100406834 0x100094000 + 3614772
3   MyApp                           0x0000000100382508 0x100094000 + 3073288
4   MyApp                           0x00000001003add94 0x100094000 + 3251604
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000198ee7b28 _pthread_body + 156
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000198ee7a8c _pthread_body + 0
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000198ee5028 thread_start + 4

Thread 14:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000198e1ef48 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000198ee6ce8 _pthread_cond_wait + 648
2   MyApp                           0x0000000100406834 0x100094000 + 3614772
3   MyApp                           0x0000000100382508 0x100094000 + 3073288
4   MyApp                           0x00000001003add94 0x100094000 + 3251604
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000198ee7b28 _pthread_body + 156
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000198ee7a8c _pthread_body + 0
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000198ee5028 thread_start + 4

Thread 15:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000198e1ef48 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000198ee6ce8 _pthread_cond_wait + 648
2   MyApp                           0x0000000100406834 0x100094000 + 3614772
3   MyApp                           0x0000000100382508 0x100094000 + 3073288
4   MyApp                           0x00000001003add94 0x100094000 + 3251604
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000198ee7b28 _pthread_body + 156
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000198ee7a8c _pthread_body + 0
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000198ee5028 thread_start + 4

Thread 16:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000198e1fb6c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000198ee5530 _pthread_wqthread + 1284
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000198ee5020 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 17:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000198e04a40 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000198e048bc mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183624108 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183621e0c __CFRunLoopRun + 1032
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183550ca0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
5   Foundation                      0x00000001844c92bc -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 308
6   MyApp                           0x0000000100403114 0x100094000 + 3600660
7   Foundation                      0x00000001845afc80 __NSThread__start__ + 1000
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000198ee7b28 _pthread_body + 156
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000198ee7a8c _pthread_body + 0
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000198ee5028 thread_start + 4

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x0000000138bd82b7
    x4: 0x0000000197b46e02   x5: 0x000000016fd67fc0   x6: 0x000000000000006e   x7: 0x0000000000000f80
    x8: 0x0000000008000000   x9: 0x0000000004000000  x10: 0x0000000000000002  x11: 0x0000000000000010
   x12: 0x0000000000000000  x13: 0x0000000000000002  x14: 0x0000000000000000  x15: 0x0000030000000300
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x0000000000000000  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x000000019f6e2000  x21: 0x000000016fd67fc0  x22: 0x0000000136f2ef90  x23: 0x0000000000000018
   x24: 0x0000000136dfaff0  x25: 0x000000019f71bfd0  x26: 0x0000000000000000  x27: 0x0000000000000002
   x28: 0x0000000000000001  fp: 0x000000016fd67f20   lr: 0x0000000198ee8ef8
    sp: 0x000000016fd67f00   pc: 0x0000000198e1f140 cpsr: 0x00000000
```

Thank you.

Comment: If it's throwing an `NSException` then where is the associated text explaining *why*?

Comment: sorry, added the full crash log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. For some reasons iPad did not have landscape orientation in supported orientations in application plist file, that's why application crashed trying to present controller in landscape mode.

Lines below these:

```
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000197b4285c __cxxabiv1::exception_cleanup_func(_Unwind_Reason_Code, _Unwind_Exception*) + 0
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001984b4094 _objc_exception_destructor(void*) + 0
9   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018366ce90 -[NSException initWithCoder:] + 0
```

Lead me to think about these lines:

```
10  UIKit                           0x0000000188c7856c -[UIViewController __supportedInterfaceOrientations] + 912
11  UIKit                           0x0000000188c77efc -[UIViewController _preferredInterfaceOrientationGivenStatusBarAndDeviceAndOrientation:] + 96
```